# Amount of atoms in 1000kg of Deuterium per Britannica

Tags: atoms, hydrogen, fusion

I was recently attempting to calculate the amount of energy released in fusion reactions, and began using as a reference the Britannica article [Energy released in fusion reactions](https://www.britannica.com/science/nuclear-fusion/Energy-released-in-fusion-reactions).  Within that article it states...

> To develop a sense for these figures, one might consider that one metric ton (1,000 kg, or almost 2,205 pounds) of deuterium would contain roughly $3 \times 10^{32}$ atoms.

I come up with a different result, as follows...

- Per Britannica, [deuterium](https://www.britannica.com/science/deuterium) has an atomic weight of 2.014.
- Therefore, a gram of deuterium will contain $6.022 \times 10^{23} / 2.014$ atoms, or $2.99 \times 10^{23}$ deuterium atoms / g.
- Since $1,000kg$ is $1,000,000g$, then $1000kg$ contains $2.99 \times 10^{23}$ deuterium atoms / g \times $1,000,000g$.
- So, I arrive at $2.99 \times 10^{29}$ deuterium atoms / $1000kg$, not the $3 \times 10^{32}$ atoms / $1000kg$ per Britannica.

The difference is 3 magnitudes.  Am I missing something or is Britannica incorrect?

Comment: You're right, Britannica's wrong.

Comment: Yes, I agree with PM. And a word to the wise: in physics we don't use commas, in the sense of "$\text{a thousand kilogram equals}$ $1,000,000\text{ g}$" Just write the million as $1000000$ (or better, use exponential notation).

Comment: @Gert and PM, thanks for the validation.  And the MathJax tip.  Ultimately I was setting about attempting to model via Navier-Stokes the First Light Fusion impact fusion technique, but then stumbled into an earlier video of theirs in which they claimed that a single fusion target was equivalent to a barrel of oil, whereas their current videos claim 2 years of home energy per target.  So before I embarked on a fluid dynamics simulation, I was seeking to calculate the theoretical peek amount of energy available via a D-T fusion reaction...

Comment: Check out http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html

Comment: @PM2Ring yeah, that's a really useful resource.  And as a follow up to my prior comment, in all fairness, First Light Fusion has evolved their solution and hence the likely reason behind the apparent discrepancy over time in output per target.  Plus they are currently proposing use of their targets via thorium reactors, which as I understand incorporates downstream fission processes which contribute to the overall energy output beyond just the D-T reaction.  All admittedly over my head... ; -)

Comment: Not sure why the question was closed.  This is not a homework question nor a check-my-work question.  This is more about questioning an authoritative source such as Britannica, which based on the validating comments is 3 magnitudes incorrect...